# System.Mail.Net cannot access closed file Exception when trying to add an attachment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, system.net.mail

Hi guys i am trying to add an attachment to an email but i am getting this weird exception which is not clear what i am doing wrong.
I am getting the attachment from a File input form

```
<div class="form-group">
<br/>
Select any files to attach to email
<div class="input-group">
    <label class="input-group-btn btn btn-default btn-file" id="attachFiles">
        Upload <input type="button" id="attach" name="Upload" style="display: none" value="Upload"/>
    </label>
    <label class="input-group-btn btn btn-default btn-file">
        Browse <input type="file" id="attachInput" multiple="false" style="display: none"/>
    </label>
    <input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="attachText" class="form-control input-group-addon"/>
</div>
<br/>
<ul id="issueFormAttachName" class="list-group list-inline"></ul>
```

Then i am getting this files via the Request and store them in a public variable to access them later via a different controller

```
  [HttpPost]
    [Route("home/saveAttachment")]
    public ActionResult SaveAttachment()
    {
        try
        {
            EmailAttachments = new EmailAttachments
            {
                FileCollectionBase = Request.Files
            };
            return Json("Ok");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json("Error occurred. Error details: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

After this i am calling my controller to send the email using this file

```
string usersToReceived = "";
            EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage
            {
                InnerHtmlBody = emailDto.EmailBody,
                Subject = $"Support enquiry ticket number #{issueId}",
                EmailHeader = "Thank you for contacting support"
            };
            emailDto.Users.ForEach(u => usersToReceived += u + ";");


            Dictionary<string, Stream> streams = new Dictionary<string, Stream>();

            //Check if attachments exist
            if (HomeController.EmailAttachments?.FileCollectionBase.Count > 0)
            {

                foreach (string streamName in HomeController.EmailAttachments.FileCollectionBase)
                {
                   streams.Add(streamName, HomeController.EmailAttachments.FileCollectionBase[streamName].InputStream);    
                }
                foreach (string file in HomeController.EmailAttachments.FileCollectionBase)
                {
                    //make sure stream is not disposed untill send is done
                    //Streams dont need to be explicitly disposed 
                    email.AddAttachment(streams[file], file, HomeController.EmailAttachments.FileCollectionBase[file]?.ContentType);
                }
            }

            email.Send(usersToReceived);

    }
```

The add attachment method just calls the native Attachment constructor `(New Attachment(_ms, fileName, mediaType)`

Now sometimes when i clear my cache and try to use above code this will work but most of the times this will throw an exception with the error Cannot access Closed file anyone knows whats going on here? i did tried having a clear cache method at the end but this did not work

Comment: Your attachements die with MVC pipeline. If you rewrite Request.Files content to another ICollection<byte[]> variable and then store that - it will be worked like a charm.

Comment: thanks will give that a go

Comment: Hi another question when do i need to rewrite them at the point of the Request.Files or later or before i call the send? Because i do not see where my app leaves the MVC pipeline

Comment: Inside SaveAttachment() method. Each action in controllers are called by reflection, so, they pipelines are different.

Comment: @AvalothOath edit your original question, not ask in the comments.

Comment: @anete.anetes thanks for that again will go work on it and let you know of the results

Comment: @anete.anetes can you post it as answer please so i can mark it as correct this has done the trick :) thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [asp.net mvc pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application) trick:

Each action in controllers are called by reflection, so, they pipelines are different.

When you **at first** store `Request.Files` in your static variable - it is **available only while pipeline not die**.

Next, you call another action and your **Request variable is different**, so, they does not store `Files` property anymore.

For avoid it, you need something for store data between requests: database, static variable, or something like that.